# Python mock function called in subprocess

Tags: python, testing, functional-testing

Having following file `handler.py`

```
import job

def worker():
   return job()
```

And following test `test_handler.py`

```
import subprocess

def test_worker():
     subprocess.Popen(['./handler.py'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

How can I mock `job` function, taking into account that `handler.py` is called in `subprocess`

Comment: What about [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)?

Comment: Edited question, this is needed in subprocess

Comment: Definitely, mock could help you! :-)

Comment: @MauroBaraldi, you mean that I can mock something in parent process and expect it to be mocked in child process?

Comment: Since, you want to test `my_func`, any external call could be mocked and handle with results.

Comment: @MauroBaraldi `my_func` is called IN subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best approach to test this feature.

Since it is a unit test, you should test the worker and check it's value.

**handler.py**

```
import job

def worker():
    return job()
```

**test_handler.py**

```
import unittest
from handler import worker

class TestHandlerCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_worker(self):
        """Test call worker should succeed."""
        self.assertEqual(worker(), True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Check if the result of method is equal to the expected. And so, adjust the method/test.

Anyway, this is an example, based on you question code.